# HTML dispplay:inline - getting underscore

Tags: html

I have the following code.
I cannot understand why after the image (videoCmera_icon.png) it puts and underscore.
I find that this happens only when I have

```
    style="display:inline;
```

Here is the code:

```
     <div id='HomeVideo1' style="display:inline;">
          <a href="#"> 
            <img src="images/videoCamera_icon.png" border="0"> 
          </a> 
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
             <span class="text3">View Video</span>  
          </a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline elements will respect whitespace between their child elements. So the whitespace between the `<img>` and the closing `</a>` tag shows up as a space (with an underline because it's part of a link).

Removing the whitespace between the `<img>` and its `<a>` tags helps:

```
<div id='HomeVideo1' style="display:inline;">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/videoCamera_icon.png" border="0" /></a> 
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><span class="text3">View Video</span></a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5abbx/